# Updating cart code for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, slim, cart

This PHP code is not working anymore from my backoffice (Slim v2) on www.arneo.vision - under PHP7 with latest WooCommerce version :

```
global $woocommerce;

var_dump($woocommerce->cart);

$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $_GET['product_id']);

var_dump($woocommerce->cart);
```

How can I update this code to work again? Please help me since I am not a professionnal developer...

Comment: Please say what error you are getting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `global $woocommerce;` with `$woocommerce->cart` is replaced by simply `WC()->cart`…

You should also test:

- If cart is not empty before trying to empty it
- If `$_GET['product_id']` is defined to avoid "Undefined index" error.

So your code should be:

```
// testing that WC()->cart is defined and it is the front end current live WC_Cart object
if( is_object (WC()->cart ) ):

var_dump(WC()->cart);

if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

if( isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) )
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $_GET['product_id'] );

var_dump(WC()->cart);

endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for your updated code but I still have a fatal error on line 7 : WC()->cart->empty_cart();

Comment: The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 7: if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_empty()

Comment: May i contact you by email for more details ? Are you french too ?!

Comment: Cart is not emptying when I am logged in as a user... it only works if I am not logged in